# How to set a hyperlink to my message in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I set a hyperlink to my message to see the price for only logged users.

But when I click on login to see price it is showing my dashboard can u please 
help me.

Answer (score 0):

In magento admin, `System > Configuration > Customer Configuration`
In login options, change Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > NO

Comment: No it is not working after selecting Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in>No

Answer (score 0):

You can set the login session to redirect the user after successfull login. Simply add these 2 lines prior to your custom link:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*'));
```

The first makes sure that a user is not redirected if the login is unsuccessful, but rather it keeps the user on the login page to retry the login.
The second tells magento to redirect the user back to the page from which he clicked the link if the login was successful.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the complete code. Please note that it is never good practice to 'hardcode' the url or the text you may wish to translate at a later date. Always use the `this->__('textstring');` function for text and magentos internal getUrls functions.

```
<?php
// get current url
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();

// set customer session for correct redirect before succesful login
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));

// set customer session for correct redirect after succesful login
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setAfterAuthUrl($currentUrl);

if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { // is logged in
?>
                <div class="price-info">
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                </div>
<?php
} else { // is not logged in
?>

    <span class="login_for_price">
        <b>
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Login to See Price') ?></a>
        </b>
    </span>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: where i has to place the code.Can u please specify

Comment: Try placing it in your price.phtml just prior to your code.

Comment: what i has to give in "getUrl('*/*/*'));"

Comment: Can u please add the code in my code and show it is not working. It is showing as before.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: I used above code but it is not working.Can u please suggest me i need it very soon

Comment: I've edited the answer - works fine here.